# Udev rule to match any usb storage device

Tags: udev

How can I implement `udev` rules for any USB mass-storage device plugged in, not just for specific one? What should be changed in `idVendor`, and `idProduct`?

```
 ACTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="usb", SYSFS{idVendor}=="0204", SYSFS{idProduct}=="6025",
     RUN+="/home/workspace/bash_script.sh"
```

Answer (score 11):

A storage device is in the `block` subsystem, so you'll want `SUBSYSTEM=="block"` in your rule, like this:

```
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="sd?", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{ID_BUS}=="usb", \
    RUN+="/path/to/script"
```

---

If you're using `systemd`, you could run a `systemd` unit each time a USB storage device is added.  Create the unit file, e.g. `/etc/systemd/system/my-usb-rule.service`:

```
[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/path/to/script
```

and the rule, e.g. `/etc/udev/rules.d/85-my-usb-rule.rules`:

```
ACTION=="add", KERNEL=="sd?", SUBSYSTEM=="block", ENV{ID_BUS}=="usb", \
    ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}="my-usb-rule.service"
```

Now `udev` will trigger `my-usb-rule.service` (which in turn will execute your script) on any usb storage device *add* event.

---

Don't forget to reload the configuration after you edit the rules/units:

```
udevadm control --reload
systemctl daemon-reload
```

Comment: When I add a USB mass storage, I would like to act on the partition(s) it contains. On udev level I can see events from 4 subsystems: usb, scsi, bdi, and block (in this order). The first 3 ones are unusable, because the partition is not yet known. The block event has ID_BUS=scsi, not usb as in your code example. I don't see any suitable attribute in the block event, that would tell me whether it is USB mass storage or not. (Investigation done using udevadm monitor and udevadm info). Unless I could trust that ID_BUS=scsi could not reasonably be anything else but USB mass storage.

Comment: @UweGeuder - nothing stopping you to use the device name [as an argument to your program](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15884426) and based on that act on the partitions...

Comment: Well, in the USB events the device name is something like /dev/bus/usb/002/040. Not sure what to do with that in my program. In the Block events the device name is something like /dev/sdb or /dev/sdb1. That's what I want, but now I'm back to the problem that ID_BUS=scsi. I got a bit further: There is a rules file 80-udisk2, which adds a property ID_DRIVE_THUMB. Not sure how robust it is, there seem to very few vendors listed. My rule file was called 70-*, so as expected my /dev/sdb did not match. Weirdly enough /dev/sdb1 matched, although my rule runs first.

Comment: Ah I just note the original question was **any** USB mass storage drive. That should work with the rule `SUBSYSTEM=="block", SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"` (note the difference with the **S**). I doubt it can always work with `ENV{ID_BUS}=="usb"` in the original answer, because I see the value scsi here. But I am working on a slightly different problem than originally asked, I want any USB stick (pendrive), but no external drives.

Comment: Actually the nasty truth is that `ENV{ID_BUS}` value is not the same on all systems. Yesterday I was working on an older system with udev 210 (I believe. Cannot check now because the machine is not on the internet), There the value was **scsi**. Now, I am on newer machine with udev 228 and the value is **usb**. For the same USB stick, I am carrying it with me. (not sure whether the udev version is the relevant factor here, could also be the kernel or any other package installing udev rules, e,g, udisks2) Still `SUBSYSTEM=="block",  SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"` (note  **S**) might be portable and safe.