# How enabled sound notifications when insert an usb flash drive into an usb port, kde plasma desktop 5.12.2, fedora 27(kde plasma spin)

Tags: fedora, kde5, plasma5

Hello pals I can't find the correct "Event source" on System-Settings>Notifications
[image]
[image]

Comment: use a udev rule; https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/229987/udev-rule-to-match-any-usb-storage-device