# Simple script to add directories

Tags: scripting, ls

I was trying to create a script that monitors the /media/user directory. When a new USB is plugged in the script would run and add the new directory to a program that now uses the new USB drive.

For example:

```
for D in ls -l /media/user
do
    directory add -d D
done
```

currently that script just literally adds `/media/user/D` as many times as there are directories in `/media/user` not the specific directory names in `/media/user/D`

The command `directory add -d` adds the directory and I want it to add `/media/user/drive1`, `/media/user/drive2` etc

Thanks I'm obviously new!

Comment: The 'D' inside the loop needs to be '$D'. [BASH Programming HowTo](https://tldp.org/HOWTO/Bash-Prog-Intro-HOWTO-7.html) ... Or check the documentation of whichever shell or scripting language you choose, for looping constructs.

Comment: It doesn't monitor any USB activity. You could try using `inotify` to monitor changes in /media/user/.

Comment: What is your OS? at least on modern Linux systems, you could consider using a UDEV rule that is triggered on the device "add" event - see for example [Udev rule to match any usb storage device](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/229987/udev-rule-to-match-any-usb-storage-device) - that way you don't need to actively monitor the directory.

Comment: Ubuntu, the reply I marked answer doesn't help the script fire when a new directory shows up in the /media/user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is very basic bash stuff. Let's go through your script.

```
for D in ls /l /media/user
do
```

You create a for-loop with the variable D which loops over

- `ls`
- `/l`
- `/media/user`

so, it will execute 3 times.

```
    directory add -d D
```

I don't know what the program `directory` is supposed to do; I don't know it. However, it is executed 3 times exactly the same way, with the same arguments:

- `add`
- `-d`
- `D`

```
done
```

The end of your for-loop.

That is not exactly the behavior that you describe; it will add always exactly 3 times litterally `D`.

Now for the improvements.

You do not want to run exactly 3 times, but you want to run for every directory in `/media/user`. So, an obvious choice would be to use `$(ls -l /media/user)`. Now, I do not know what kind of format your `directory` program expects as argument, but if it isn't

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 ljm users   27164672 Jun 19 00:30 mikrotik-6.47.10.iso
```

then you probably do not want the `-l` option. Also, parsing the output of `ls` is in general a bad idea. So, what you're probably looking for is

```
for D in /media/user/* 
do
```

Next id your `directory` program. It is always called with `D` as last argument. Not the value of `D`, that would be `$D`. That means that you probably want to

```
directory add -d $D
```

But, if the directory name has a space in it, this will split the directory name into two arguments. So quoting is required:

```
directory add -d "$D"
```

Hope that gets you a bit better on track.

Comment: Thanks for the breakdown.  It is very simple and I'm just learning. I appreciate the very descriptive steps.  I got it to work.  I think I was confusing everyone by using 'directory' as my program, which it is not. I should have chosen the generic 'program' in hindsight.

Comment: is there a way to have the script trigger when a new usb drive is attached? monitor the folder or as a suggestion above

Answer (score 0):

1. Don't use `ls` in a script.
2. There is no "directory" command; `mkdir` creates directories, though. You can read its 'man' page.

So try replacing that first line as `for D in /media/user/*`

Comment: He is not using `$(ls -l ...)`; he is using literally `ls`. There's no rule against that. `directory` is his apparently his own program.